# c# methods within methods

Tags: c#, methods

In Delphi, you can define functions within functions, example :

```
function Foo : integer;
var myvar : integer;
    function Foo1;
    begin
        myvar := 42;
    end;
begin
    result := myvar;
end;
```

This returns 42 as expected because Foo1 has access to Foo's myvar.

Is there any equivalent in C#?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in C#. All the functions in C# are class level. You can create private or internal functions to restrict access from another classes.

Comment: @nipiv, while what you said is true, the modern C# compiler has ways of getting around this restriction to make it "appear" as though you are doing the same thing as Delphi, resulting in the same functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are many ways to do this. One way is to declare [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) or [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegates as follows:

```
void Foo()
{
    Func<int,int> f = x => x+1;
    //or
    Func<int,int> ff = x => {
        return x+1;
    };
    var r = f(1); //2
    var rr = ff(2); //3

    Func<int,int,int> add => (a,b) => a+b;
    var rrr = add(2,3); //5
}
```

The shorthand declaration ( `=>` ) is commonly used in Linq. See [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

There are many generic `Func` and `Action` delegates declared in the BCL (or whatever it's called nowdays) to allow for all but the stupidest length parameter lists. You could always declare your own generic delegates if you need more parameters.

Comment: An interesting tidbit regarding this is that the functions you declare actually get moved outside of the function Foo(), and state is maintained by creating an auto-generated class where all shared variables are public members...but I digress :)